# Projecting mySQL database, how to deal with multiple categories

Tags: php, mysql

I need a help with projecting my database. The purpose of this database will be to show offers in different categories. There are 1-6 categories to each item. There are around 80 categories types, so I decided to make three tables as below:

```
table1:

ID  Item_id
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5

table2:

ID Item_id Category
1   1      cat55
2   1      cat56
3   1      cat57
4   1      cat58
5   2      cat42
6   2      cat43
7   2      cat44
8   2      cat45
9   3      cat42 
etc.

table3:

Category_id  category_name
cat55        apples
cat56        oranges
cat57        bananas
cat58        pineapples
```

Am I doing this right? I've got a problem to make proper sql query to show my categories in php, because when I use this query:

```
    SELECT table1.*, table2.*, table3.*
       FROM table1
       INNER JOIN table2
       ON table1.item_id = table2.item_id
       INNER JOIN table3
       ON table2.category=table3.category_id
```

It only gives me the first category name, when I need all of them and show them like this:

```
Item 1: apples, oranges, bananas, pineapples
Item 2: cat42, cat43, cat44, cat45
Item 3: cat42
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it wrong query or I need to change the database structure to like this

```
table 1 and 3 unchanged

table 2:
ID Item_id  c1      c2      c3      c4      c5      c6  
1   1       cat55   cat56   cat57   cat58   null    null
2   2       cat42   cat43   cat44   cat45   null    null
3   3       cat42   null    null    null    null    null
```

I'm using foreach loop, so I can do only one query, I know that more queries are possible, but I need to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: @Strawberry, sure in php after this query

Comment: Your query is fine. Your PHP is faulty, but you've not shown us any of that.

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't show it, because I don't want to make it too complicated. This is simple question - what type of database structure should I choose to have an access to all elements, php isn't a problem

Comment: Are you asking me the question, or telling me the answer?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm just curious

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch all names in single row for each item, following query will work:

```
SELECT table1.Item_Id,Group_Concat(t3.category_name separator ',') as Category_Name
       FROM table1
       INNER JOIN table2
       ON table1.item_id = table2.item_id
       INNER JOIN table3
       ON table2.category=table3.category_id
Group by table1.Item_Id;
```

I don't find any problem in your DB Structure.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry!! I've made mistake in `Group_concat()`, Please try the edited answer.

Comment: okay, I'll try but it seems to be more complicated, because I need to get access to them seperately. for example: I need to get 2nd category of item1 - update it or delete and so on...

Comment: So you only want to select all the category names for each items using query and later want to display with separated commas using php. Is it so?

Comment: Yes, but I want to have access to them seperately. Maybe I need to ask different question

Comment: In that case, yes you should change your structure as suggested in your question

Comment: @gileneusz You shouldn't be changing your structure (although you do have a surplus of ids)

Comment: Thank you for your help, this might be a better alternative, however in this case I would need to make connection within each column to table3

Comment: I am aware of that .